# Imputation mixed data caret (preProcess)

Tags: r, missing-data, r-caret

I am trying to impute data before modeling with random forest for example.

I have categorical and continuous features. I would like to use the function kNN (VIM package) to impute my data. But I can't use this function in the preProcess function of caret and the knn imputation of this function does not handle mixed data.

How can I impute mixed data in the preProcess function ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of right now, it will only impute continuous predictors (which you can get via dummy variables).

You could write your won [custom method](http://topepo.github.io/caret/custom_models.html) to use that function for pre-processing if you like. [This example](http://topepo.github.io/caret/custom_models.html#Illustration4) might help.

Once I get through the work for my day job, improving `preProcess` is the next major task for package development.

Thanks,

Max

Comment: This example ends in 404 unfortunately. It's been a while since the answer. are there any updates to it?